# Rails ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method for Nill class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, devise

I know that this is quite a common problem but none of the other responses has been able to help me.

I am currently trying to create tests for my website but I always get the error

> ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method

for quite a lot of my methods which usually result in a `Nill` class. The website uses devise for logging in.

Here is a test that I'm trying to run. I made sure my fixtures are loaded into the test database

```
    require 'test_helper'

class PagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  def setup
    sign_in User.first
  end

  def teardown
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end


  test "should get voting" do
    get :voting
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

And these are the error messages when trying to run the test

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    config/initializers/addChallenges.rb:22:in `findChallenges'
    app/views/pages/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb__190802989_69818040'
    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'
config/initializers/addChallenges.rb:22:in `findChallenges'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb__190802989_69818040'
test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'

Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    config/initializers/addIdeas.rb:25:in `findIdeas'
    app/views/pages/voting.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_pages_voting_html_erb___557022735_70668940'
    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'
config/initializers/addIdeas.rb:25:in `findIdeas'
app/views/pages/voting.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_pages_voting_html_erb___557022735_70668940'
test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'
Finished in 0.31402s
2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When tracking the error in this case, this line is shown as problematic `resp = http.get(url.path, headers)` This is my full addIdeas code but the addChallenges one is quite similar.

```
class AddIdeas
  #a method that will find all the challenge ideas for a user and then store them in our databse
  def self.findIdeas(email,challengeId)

    require "net/http"
    require "uri"
    require 'json'
    require 'active_record'

    p= People.find_by_email(email)

    uri_string = 'http://sideways6.com/api/V1/Idea/Challenge/'
    uri_string << challengeId.to_s

    #make the http request with the headers
    url = URI.parse(uri_string)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    headers = {
        'Authorization' => p.basic,
        'UserId' => p.userId,
        'AuthorizationToken' => p.auth_tok
    }

    #retrieve a get response
    resp = http.get(url.path, headers)
    #if response is okay parse the challenge ids and add them to the person table for that user
    if resp.code.to_s == '200'
        if resp.body.to_s != 'null'
          puts parsed = JSON.parse(resp.body)
          ids = ""
          parsed.each do |element|
            addIdeas(element, challengeId)
            ids << "#{element['IdeaId']},"
          end
          c = Challenges.find_by_challengeId(challengeId)
          c.ideaIds = ids
          c.save
        end
    end
  end

  def self.addIdeas(element, challengeId)
    i = Ideas.find_by_ideaId(element['IdeaId'])

    if i == nil
      i = Ideas.create(:ideaId => element['IdeaId'], :title => element['Title'], :description => element['Description'], :challengeIds => challengeId, :score=>1000, :faceOff => 0, :wins =>0)
    end
    if i != nil
      i.ideaId = (element['IdeaId'])
      i.title = (element['Title'])
      i.description = (element['Description'])
      i.challengeIds = challengeId
      i.save
    end
  end


  def self.findAllIdeas(email)
    p = People.find_by_email(email)
    ids = p.challenges
    splitted = ids.split(",")
    counter = splitted.length
    i =0
    while i < counter.to_i do
      findIdeas(email, splitted[i])
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

addChallenges file

```
class AddChallenges
  #a method that will find all the challenge ideas for a user and then store them in our databse
  def self.findChallenges(email)

    require "net/http"
    require "uri"
    require 'json'
    require 'active_record'

    p= People.find_by_email(email)

    #make the http request with the headers
    url = URI.parse('http://sideways6.com/api/V1/Challenge/All')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    headers = {
        'Authorization' => p.basic,
        'UserId' => p.userId,
        'AuthorizationToken' => p.auth_tok
    }

    #retrieve a get response
    resp = http.get(url.path, headers)
    #if response is okay parse the challenge ids and add them to the person table for that user
    if resp.code.to_s == '200'
      puts parsed = JSON.parse(resp.body)
      ids = ""
      parsed.each do |element|
        addChallenges(element)
        ids << "#{element['ChallengeId']},"
      end

      p = People.find_by_email(email)
      p.challenges = ids
      p.save
    end
  end

  def self.addChallenges(element)
    c = Challenges.find_by_challengeId(element['ChallengeId'])
    if c == nil
      c = Challenges.create(:challengeId => element['ChallengeId'], :title => element['Title'], :description => element['Description'])
    end
    if c != nil
      c.challengeId = (element['ChallengeId'])
      c.title = (element['Title'])
      c.description = (element['Description'])
      c.save
    end
  end

  def self.retrieveChallengeObject(challengeId)
    c = Challenges.find_by_challengeId(challengeId)
  end

end
```

My pages controller as requested

```
class PagesController <ApplicationController

  def home
    @current_nav_identifier = :home
  end
end
```

Index page

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';</script>
<body>
<noscript>
  <div class='warning-page-cover'>
    <div class='alert alert-info'>
      <h2>Sorry about that, it appears that you are using a web browser without JavaScript which prevents us offering you a rich online experience.</h2>
      <p>Please enable JavaScript or use a different web browser, or alternatively contact the CiCS Helpdesk for assistance.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</noscript>
<%AddChallenges.findChallenges(current_user.email)%>
<%AddIdeas.findAllIdeas(current_user.email)%>

<div id='wrap'>
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' id='main-nav'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>

      <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
        <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'index')%>">
          <%= image_tag('/logo.png', :alt => "Sideways 6 Logo", size:"203x50") %>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class='collapse navbar-collapse'  id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        </ul>
        <% if true # user_signed_in? %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><%= link_to fa_icon('index', text: 'Refresh Challenges'), root_path  ,  method: :get %></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <%= link_to '#', data: { toggle: :dropdown }, class: 'dropdown-toggle' do %>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <% p = People.find_by_email(current_user.email)%>
                    <% fName = p.firstName %>
                    <% if fName != nil %>
                        <%= fa_icon('user', text: fName )%>
                    <%end%>
                    <% if fName == nil %>
                        <%= fa_icon('user', text: current_user.email) %>
                    <%end%>
                    <b class="caret"></b>

                <% end %>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <%# log out path is usually: destroy_user_session_path %>
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('index',  text: Score.retrieveUserScore(current_user.email)), root_path , method: :get %>
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('challenges', text:'All Challenges'), challenges_path, method: :get, title: "See all Challenges"  %>
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('sign-out', text: 'Log out'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :get, title: "Log out of the system" %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>Select A Challenge To Vote On</h1>
      <% p = People.find_by_email(current_user.email)  %>
      <% ids = p.challenges %>
      <% splitted = ids.split(",") %>
      <% counter = splitted.length %>


      <p class="lead">Please Select One</p>
      <% i =0 %>
      <% while i < counter.to_i do %>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <% c = AddChallenges.retrieveChallengeObject(splitted[i]) %>
          <% if Vote.canVote(splitted[i]) == true %>
          <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'voting')%>?challengeId=<%=(splitted[i])%>" class="challenge-select" data-challengeid="<%=(splitted[i])%>">
            <div class="well clickable">
                <h4><%= c.title %></h4>
                <p class="text-center"> <%= c.description %> </p>
            </div>
          </a>
           <% end %>
        </div>
        <% i+=1 %>
        <% if i != counter %>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <% c = AddChallenges.retrieveChallengeObject(splitted[i]) %>
          <% if Vote.canVote(splitted[i]) == true %>
          <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'voting')%>?challengeId=<%=(splitted[i])%>" class="challenge-select" data-challengeid="<%=(splitted[i])%>">
          <div class="well clickable">
            <h4><%= c.title %></h4>
            <p class="text-center"><%= c.description %></p>
          </div>
          </a>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <%end%>
    </div>
          <% i+=1 %>
      <%end%>

    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And voting html

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';</script>

<% require 'digest/sha1'
    salt = '%+5)_' %>

<% AddIdeas.findIdeas(current_user.email,params[:challengeId]) %>

<% if params[:winner] != nil
    concat = "#{salt}#{params[:challengeId]}#{params[:winner]}#{params[:loser]}#{salt}"
    hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(concat)
    if hash == params[:hash]
        Score.updateScore(params[:winner],params[:loser])
        Score.userScore(current_user.email)
    end
end %>
<div id='wrap'>
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' id='main-nav'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>

      <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
        <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'index')%>">
          <%= image_tag('/logo.png', :alt => "Sideways 6 Logo", size:"203x50") %>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class='collapse navbar-collapse'  id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        </ul>
        <% if true # user_signed_in? %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><%= link_to fa_icon('index', text: 'Change Challenge'), root_path  ,  method: :get %></li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <%= link_to '#', data: { toggle: :dropdown }, class: 'dropdown-toggle' do %>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <% p = People.find_by_email(current_user.email)%>
                    <% fName = p.firstName %>
                    <% if fName != nil %>
                        <%= fa_icon('user', text: fName )%>
                    <%end%>
                    <% if fName == nil %>
                        <%= fa_icon('user', text: current_user.email) %>
                    <%end%>
                    <b class="caret"></b>

                <% end %>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <%# log out path is usually: destroy_user_session_path %>
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('index',  text: Score.retrieveUserScore(current_user.email)), root_path , method: :get %>
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('challenges', text:'All Challenges'), challenges_path, method: :get, title: "See all Challenges"  %>
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('sign-out', text: 'Log out'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :get, title: "Log out of the system" %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="main">
    <% c = Challenges.find_by_challengeId(params[:challengeId]) %>
    <% ids = c.try(:ideaIds) %>
    <% splitted = ids.try(:split, ",") %>
    <% shuffle = splitted.try(:shuffle) %>
    <% firstIdea = shuffle.try(:first) %>
    <% lastIdea = shuffle.try(:last) %>
    <% f = Ideas.find_by_ideaId(firstIdea)%>
    <% l = Ideas.find_by_ideaId(lastIdea)%>
    <h1><%=c.try(:title)%></h1>
    <p class="lead">Which best solves the challenge?</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <% challengeId = params[:challengeId]
        winner = f.try(:ideaId)
        loser = l.try(:ideaId)
        concat = "#{salt}#{challengeId}#{winner}#{loser}#{salt}"
        hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(concat) %>
        <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'voting')%>?challengeId=<%=(params[:challengeId])%>&winner=<%=(f.try(:ideaId))%>&loser=<%=(l.try(:ideaId))%>&hash=<%=(hash)%>" class="idea-vote" data-challengeid="<%=(params[:challengeId])%>" data-winner="<%=(f.try(:ideaId))%>" data-loser="<%=(l.try(:ideaId))%>" data-hash="<%=(hash)%>">
        <div class="well clickable">
          <h4><%= f.try(:title) %></h4>
          <p class="text-center"><%= f.try(:description)%></p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <% challengeId = params[:challengeId]
        winner = l.try(:ideaId)
        loser = f.try(:ideaId)
        concat = "#{salt}#{challengeId}#{winner}#{loser}#{salt}"
        hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(concat) %>
        <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'voting')%>?challengeId=<%=(params[:challengeId])%>&winner=<%=(l.try(:ideaId))%>&loser=<%=(f.try(:ideaId))%>&hash=<%=(hash)%>" class="idea-vote" data-challengeid="<%=(params[:challengeId])%>" data-winner="<%=(l.try(:ideaId))%>" data-loser="<%=(f.try(:ideaId))%>" data-hash="<%=(hash)%>">
        <div class="well clickable">
          <h4><%=l.try(:title)%></h4>
          <p class="text-center"><%=l.try(:description)%></p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="<%= url_for(:controller=> 'pages', :action => 'voting')%>?challengeId=<%=(params[:challengeId])%>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Skip <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried modifying the methods with `try()` and it seems to sometimes resolve the issue but after that the `try()` causes problems with the website itself. Sometimes the error message would redirect me to the html view file itself where methods are used.

EDIT:
Ok after fixing the headers I now get

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    config/initializers/addIdeas.rb:61:in `findAllIdeas'
    app/views/pages/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb__1448445017_66568380'
    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'
config/initializers/addIdeas.rb:61:in `findAllIdeas'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb__1448445017_66568380'
test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'

Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `score' for #<People:0x000000085d17b0>
    config/initializers/score.rb:50:in `retrieveUserScore'
    app/views/pages/voting.html.erb:56:in `_app_views_pages_voting_html_erb___944539514_69504160'
    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'
config/initializers/score.rb:50:in `retrieveUserScore'
app/views/pages/voting.html.erb:56:in `_app_views_pages_voting_html_erb___944539514_69504160'
test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'
Finished in 0.53103s
2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The score.rb file

```
class Score
  def self.updateScore(winner, loser)
    Math.exp(1)
    w = Ideas.find_by_ideaId(winner)
    l = Ideas.find_by_ideaId(loser)
    # updatewinner
    # games W played = get number of times the winner has matched up against other ideas
    # winner new score = winner score + (1000/games W played) (1+ 1/(1 + Math.exp(loser score - winner score)))
    w.faceOff += 1
    w.save

    lScore = l.score
    wScore = w.score
    wGames = w.faceOff

    newWScore = wScore + (500/wGames)*(1-(1/(1 + Math.exp(lScore - wScore))))

    l.faceOff += 1
    l.save
    lGames = l.faceOff

    newLScore = lScore + (500/lGames)*(-1/(1+ Math.exp(wScore - lScore)))

    puts "New Winner Score "
    puts newWScore
    w.score = newWScore
    w.save

    puts "New Loser Score "
    puts newLScore
    l.score = newLScore
    l.save

    puts newWScore
    # updateloser
    # games L played = get number of times the loser has matched up against other ideas
    # loser new score = loser score + (1000/games L played) (1+ 1/(Math.exp(winner score - loser score)))
  end

  def self.userScore(email)
    p = People.find_by_email(email)
    score = p.score
    newScore = score + 1
    p.score = newScore
    p.save
  end

  def self.retrieveUserScore(email)
    p = People.find_by_email(email)
    score = 'Score: ' << p.score.to_s

  end

end
```

Comment: Please add your PagesController and the index and voting templates

Comment: Done. The controller itself is quite scarce though

Comment: Sorry, guess that wasn't needed. What I'm actually interested in is your addChallenges.rb file

Comment: I uploaded it. Right after the addIdeas.rb

Comment: How certain are you that 'p' isn't nil? It's the only thing that occurs to me right now

Comment: Well the website itself works. I don't get any errors there and all my functionality seems to be there. Stuff is in the database as it's supposed to as well.

Comment: I agree, if I run the same thing, setting `url` to `nil` it says path is undefined. If I set any of the 3 params in `header` to `nil` I get the same `undefined method 'strip' for nil:NilClass` This is all in the `AddIdeas` class, line 25

Comment: could you log the header params to make sure none of them are coming as nil or some invalid value from your database?

Comment: A thing worth noting is that I am actually pulling data from an API. Data like users, challenges and ideas

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did some testing:

Your error is that one of your `header` params is coming back from your database as `nil`

I can replicate your error by setting

```
headers = {                                                                                                                            
    'Authorization' => nil,                                                                                                            
    'UserId' => nil,                                                                                                                   
    'AuthorizationToken' => nil
}
```

and running `http.get(url.path, headers)`

What you can do to avoid the exception and let the API return an error is test for nil and replace it with an empty string `""`

Ex: `'Authorization' => p.basic || ""`

EDIT: For your edit above...

There are two errors:

1. `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass`
   This one happens because of:

   `ids = p.challenges`
    `splitted = ids.split(",")`

If ids is nil, you can't call `split` on it. You need to add a check and return at that point.

2. `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'score' for #<People:0x000000085d17b0>`

Your `People` model doesn't have a `score` method

Comment: Ok This actually fixes some of the problems but it just seems to spawn new undefined method errors. Editing them up in the original post.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your new errors. You're probably gonna find even more errors after this. Basically everything you query should have a null check, and you need to decide what to do if your result is nil. What should your app do?

Comment: It would never on its own result in a nil but it seems like the minitest is complaining that in some case it actually might do that. If there was just a way to silence the complaints...  I haven't encountered errors with my system as of yet and i am confident that it works as it should at this stage.

Comment: If you're getting an outright error, then it is in fact hitting nil values for some reason.

Comment: Do you think it might be caused by a problem with the tests themselve or something with the fixture?

Comment: Something with the fixture most likely. Remember the test db is separate from the development db. You can use plain ruby to create users and other objects in the test db if you're having trouble with fixtures, just remember to clean up the db

Comment: I am using a simple user and password fixture and then as you can see in the test I have the user sign in in the setup and I can see the user being created in the database itself. But i suppose it is possible that the login is being denied.

Comment: if your Person fixture is missing `basic` `userId`, and `auth_tok` then your code would get them as nil, which would cause the errors you're seeing

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally managed to fix my issue. There was a problem with the test database not being populated by everything even though i used `rake db:test:clone` and `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='test'``

Comment: Glad to be of help! Sometimes it's the last thing we think causing all our problems :P